# Object has no method getColumnType

Tags: javascript, playframework, google-visualization

In my play application I send some JSON output to my view in order to show a google pie chart. Things go wrong when it renders the js

```
Object {cols: [{id: 'title', label: 'Title' , type: 'string'},{id: 'unitPrice', label: 'Unit Price', type: 'int'}],rows: [ has no method 'getColumnType'×
```

This message is all I get from trying and draw a pie chart using the Google Chart API.
What does this even mean? "no method 'getColumnType'"

Any insight would be greatly appriciated. my code, so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>PayView</title>
   <head>    
        <script type="text/javascript">var pieChartData;</script>
        <script type="text/javascript">var loads = 0;</script>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>  
        <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});      
            google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
                ++loads;
                if (loads == 2)
                drawVisualization();
            });

            function drawVisualization() {
                $('.log').html('pieChartData: ' + pieChartData);
                new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
                draw(pieChartData, {title:"Purchases"});
            }               

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(function() {
                    pieChartData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                    pieChartData.addColumn('string', 'Title');
                    pieChartData.addColumn('number', 'Unit Price');

                    var getJSon2 = $.ajax({
                        url: '@routes.Application.getJson()',
                        processData:false,
                        type: 'GET',
                        beforeSend:function(jqXHR, settings){                   
                            jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                        },
                        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){                         
                            ++loads;
                            if (loads == 2)
                                drawVisualization();
                            process_items(data);   
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        },
                        complete: function(jqXHR,textStatus){                   
                        }   
                    );

                    var process_items = function(data){                     
                        pieChartData.addRows(data.length);
                        $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                            $("#purchases").append("<li>" + item.name + "</li>");
                            pieChartData.setCell(index, 0, item.title);
                            pieChartData.setCell(index, 1, item.unitPrice); 
                        });
                    });
                });         
            };  
        });     
        </script>       
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="log"></div>
        <div id="purchases"></div>
        <div id="visualization" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make sure you declare that "loads" global - just put `var loads=0;` at the top, before the Google stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also give a parameter to the function

```
function drawChart(draw)
{
    if(draw > 0)
    {
      var data=....;
      var options = ....;
      var chart = ....;
      chart.draw(data,options)
    }
}
```

And you call this function in your ajax giving a value like `drawChart(1)`

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use the "googleData" string built from the results of the ajax call before that call has completed.

You're going to have to rig up something that waits for the completion of the google library load as well as your ajax call.  That could look something like this:

```
        var loads = 0;
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});      
        google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
          ++loads;
          if (loads == 2)
            drawVisualization();
        });

    // then in your "ready" handler:


            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                process_items(data);
                ++loads:
                if (loads == 2)
                  drawVisualization();
            },
```

That (inelegant) setup increments a counter when the ajax call finishes and when the google thing finishes.  Both handlers check to see if they're the last one to finish, and invoke the "draw" function if so.

Comment: Spot on, Pointy. The issue is the delay you are mentioning. If i run the JS from firebug with a breakpoint stopping execusion for a little while... then the pie chart gets drawn flawlessly. I've inserted your code, but with no luck. I've edited the code in the question with your suggestion. Am I doing it right?

Comment: by the way, why is it inelegant? if it does the work... are there any best practices in such cases?

Comment: Well there's a "Deferred" mechanism in jQuery that would be somewhat neater. You could wrap the Google API call in that, and then use a jQuery mechanism to combine the two. I'll re-read the question and see if I can find an issue.

Comment: @Pointy  I have a similar issue in my post [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411545/object-has-no-method-getcolumntype-error).  Maybe you can offer some help to me.  I have tried to implement the fix you suggested here but cannot seem to fit it to my issue.  Your help is greatly appreciated.